# Set class field size at runtime C++

Tags: c++, class

I have a certain class, with a certain field named X, X can be a uint32_t or a uint64_t.

I want to design the class such that X's type is set at runtime, currently i just split the classes to one class where X is uint32_t and another class where X is uint64_t.

```
//example class
class Test {
public:
    std::string name;
    int age;
    uint32_t/uint64_t X;
};
```

This led to a lot of code duplication,

do you have any idea How i can design the class hierarchy?

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Use templates or code generation. To decide which, please post expected runtime code. See also: [mcve].

Comment: Wanted runtime code:
Test* s = new Test();
std::cout << sizeof(s->X) << std::endl;
will print the size according to size resolved at runtime

Comment: @yairkoskas There is literally no way to achieve _exactly_ that behavior in C++. Even with code duplication.

Comment: can you thing of a way of implementing this with as little code duplication as possible?

Comment: @yairkoskas There is __no__ such way. All calls to `sizeof` in C++ are computed in compile-time. You cannot have a line of code in `main()` which will print different `sizeof()` depending on run-time behavior. You, however, most probably may solve your initial problem where the need to have a dynamic field arose initially. Please describe the context in your question and there will be a higher chance of getting an answer. For example, `std::variant` may be a good fit in your case, or it may be not. Similarly for templates, for inheritance, and for `std::any`.

Comment: std::variant is great! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score -2):

Use pointers. Like...

```
 class Test {
   public:
    std::string name;
    int age;
    uint32_t/uint64_t * X;
   }; //add constructor to it. and constructor have pointers also 
   //like uint32_t * X = new uint32[//size];
```

Comment: Besides answering a question i didn't ask, how will i get the size of the thing it's pointing at?